# write.table columns do not align with blanks

Tags: r, write.table

I have a mostly blank data frame that can be read using the input below:

```
structure(list(var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), var2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), var6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    var7 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), var8 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", 
"var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8", "var9", "var10"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to write this to a TXT file where it looks like everything is formatted properly and can be easily opened in Excel (I know about `write.xlsx` and while it solves this problem I want the file to be in `txt` format).

```
write.table(df3, file="test.txt", quote = FALSE, na = " \t", row.names = FALSE)
```

I tried this but the values do not align properly: for example, the values that should be under `var7` show up on `var6` intead. Also, while Excel manages to read the columns as being separate, the header row which contains the variable names gets read as one long vector. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Use `write.table(df3, file="test.txt", quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", na="", row.names = FALSE)` Note  that `sep = "\t"` is used instead of `na = " \t"` and set `na=""`.

Comment: While this works, if I use this the NAs will also be written, and I don't want that.

Comment: @vashts85 just set `na=""`

Answer (score 0):

If I write:

```
write.table(df3, file="test.txt", quote = FALSE, sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, na="")
```

Then it works. I followed Jilber's advice about using `sep="\t"` and also doing the this for the `na` option, as otherwise the NAs would show up in the file.